# External API Method Placement and Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a site that displays a section with stack overflow queries related to a post. To get these, it uses the SO API to search SO for posts similar to the title of the post on my site.

My question is, where should I put this method? It's directly related to posts in that it uses a post's title to make the API call. But it's also directly related to the controller in that it returns data that must be passed on to the view. I doubt I'd want to put code for even a simple API call inside of an actual view. Maybe I should put it in a library/helper method?

Also, once I've decided where to put the method, how should I test it without having to call the API every time? I'm trying to read up on stubs but I'm getting confused. It'd be nice to have an example in a context like this and build my knowledge from there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use gem for stub http-requests.
I used for it [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) which has integration with `rspec`, `test/unit` or `minitest`

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should put it in a new model (without inheriting from ActiveRecord). Then make the controller call it to get the data and pass it on to the view.
If you'd like to test this model - you can use "fakeweb" which is a gem that allows you to mock http requests with your own results.

https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb

Comment: Any particular reason for making a new model? All of the method's logic is related to the Post model, and the Stackoverflow search method would be the only method of its kinda. No associated attributes go along with the model. Does that really warrant a whole new model?

Comment: Since it is using a new data source (http source), I'd prefer to make put it in a new model. Just like if you were to get this data from a different MySQL table - you would have made a model for it.